# How to perform a query in Firestore string field to match against multiple values?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in Firestore that has a field `status` which is either "COMPLETE" "INCOMPLETE" or "ON HOLD"

How would I perform a query that only returns the documents matching "COMPLETE" **and** "INCOMPLETE"?

```
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('tasks')
    .where('status', isEqualTo: 'COMPLETE')
    .where('status', isEqualTo: 'INCOMPLETE');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `whereIn` operator which will fetch documents where the provided field (in this case `status`) has either of the values provided in the array/list passed:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('tasks').where('status', whereIn: ['COMPLETE','INCOMPLETE']);
```